# How can I create a direct 8khz audio pipe in Ubuntu?

Tags: audio, devices

I'm interested in creating musical programs like these:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtQdIYUtAHg&feature=player_embedded

Essentially these programs just generate sequences of integers, which (apparently), when fed directly into a 8khz audio stream (like "/dev/audio"), produce interesting music.

My problem is that my system does not have /dev/audio. In fact, looking through my /dev, it's unclear to me whether any of the devices is a direct audio interface.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a nice package which will let me pipe in a stream of numbers from the command line, and produce a matching 8Khz audio output?
2. If not, how might I go about directly accessing my audio device?

Comment: Answered my own question, but can't put it in as an answer yet (not enough reputation). This works fine for me:

./a.out | aplay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked out fine for me:

```
./a.out | aplay
```

Comment: Thanks! And you probably have enough reputation now to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the video it looks like they are using PCM.  On Ubuntu try using /dev/snd/pcm*

Comment: So I've tried ./a.out > /dev/snd/pcm[some identifier] for all /dev/snd/pcm*. None of them produce audible sounds. Is there something extra I need to do?

Comment: You might need to set the volume:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/amixer.1.html